# Создание новой строки в таблице

Tags: delphi, sql-server

Имеется код для создания новой строки в таблице БД

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
DataModule2.AdoQuery1.close;    
DataModule2.AdoQuery1.SQL.text:='INSERT INTO files(id_file_vkr, file_vkr, id_student) 
VALUES (:id_file_vkr, :file_vkr, :id_student)';
DataModule2.AdoQuery1.Parameters.Refresh;
DataModule2.AdoQuery1.Parameters[0].Value:=DataModule2.ADODataset1.FieldByName
('id_file_vkr').AsInteger;
DataModule2.AdoQuery1.Parameters[1].Value:=DataModule2.ADODataset1.FieldByName
('file_vkr').As;<-----
DataModule2.AdoQuery1.Parameters[2].Value:=DataModule2.ADODataset1.FieldByName
('id_student').AsInteger;
DataModule2.AdoQuery1.ExecSQL;
end;
```

Вопрос: как правильно написать периметр поля, в которое загружается doc файл?(varbinary(max))**( где стрелка)**

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
DataModule2.AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('file_vkr').LoadFromStream(ADODataSet1.CreateBlobStream(ADODataSet1.FieldByName('file_vkr'),bmRead),ftVarBytes);
```

Comment: Спасибо ,только на bmRead ругается, видимо что-то нужно подсоединить

Comment: @Ник_qd, 

    uses DB;

Comment: Not enough actual parameters

Comment: @Ник_qd, поправил в ответе.